# How can I set a CountDownTimer in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

Using the CountDownTimer, is there a way I can let the user choose how much time the timer will count?

```
val timer = object : CountDownTimer(time * 1000, 1000) {
        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
            bntTimer.text = (millisUntilFinished / 1000).toString()
            if (!on)
                turnOn()
        }

        override fun onFinish() {
            bntTimer.text = "Timer"
            if (on)
                turnOff()
        }
    }
```

In this code the variable time is initialized with 5, but before starting the timer, the user can change it. However, it always count 5 seconds.

Here is where the variable time got modified

```
 bntTimer.setOnClickListener(){
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(etTime.text)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Por favor, informe o tempo.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Timer Contando", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            time = etTime.text.toString().toLong()
            timer.start()
        }
    }
```

Comment: I presume the issue is on where the variable `time` got modified, maybe you can help to provide any other code that shows where you modify the `time` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are making the timer object first then changing the time variable which has no longer effect on the existing timer object. So you must make the timer object again after changing the time variable.

You can make a function like below or a function with time as a parameter.

```
fun starTimer(){

    time = etTime.text.toString().toLong()

    val timer = object : CountDownTimer(time * 1000, 1000) {
        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
            bntTimer.text = (millisUntilFinished / 1000).toString()
            if (!on)
                turnOn()
        }

        override fun onFinish() {
            bntTimer.text = "Timer"
            if (on)
                turnOff()
        }
    }.start()
}
```

Then call the startTimer() function whenever you need it. Something like in your case

```
 bntTimer.setOnClickListener(){
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(etTime.text)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Por favor, informe o tempo.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Timer Contando", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            startTimer()
        }
    }
```